# How hide Joomla custom field in homepage and category menu?

Tags: php, joomla

If I create custom field in Joomla, it's will show in homepage (featured article) and blog category menu.

I want custom fields to only show in a single article. It should be hidden in the homepage (featured articles) and blog category menu.

Where can I setting it or modify in PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

The files you need to override are at `\components\com_content\views\featured\tmpl\default_item.php` and `\components\com_content\views\category\tmpl\blog_item.php`

Important : core files should be overridden in your template, and the core code left unchanged.

The fields themselves are generated by the lines

```
<?php // Content is generated by content plugin event "onContentBeforeDisplay" ?>
<?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>
```

Note that removing these lines will also stop any other plugin which uses this area from working.  As far as I can tell, the only other thing to use it is the voting system.  If you need that, then you may need to write a bespoke plugin or just hide the area with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the override of Layout com_fileds - field.
(copy the file render.php from components/com_fields/layouts/field/ to templatename/html/layouts/com_fields/field/)

Add two new variables and one more condition on the if condiction

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$app  = JFactory::getApplication();
$view = $app->input->getCmd('view', '');

if (!key_exists('field', $displayData) || $view != 'article')
{
    return;
}
```